# GeSHi shows no syntax colors with Joomla 3.3

Tags: joomla-3.x, extensions, plugin

I have been using the GeSHi plugin for syntax highlighting on my Joomla 3 installation for few weeks.  The highlighting has been working fine.  But ever since I upgraded to Joomla 3.3 the highlighting has no colors.  The code is still being formatted as before, but without the color.

I'm entering the tags (i.e. `<pre xml:lang="SQL">`) as before using the HTML editor.

Has anyone else noticed this or knows what this may be happening?

Thanks

Comment: What was your initial Joomla version? 3.0, 3.1 or 3.2?

Comment: Joomla 3.2 was where I tested GeSHi with color.

Comment: Can you check all the GeSHi subfolders in the plugin exist please https://github.com/drmmr763/JoomlaExtensionDevelopment/tree/master/plugins/content/geshi/geshi/geshi? Have you also checked that the CSS isn't now being overridden from somewhere else? (using chrome dev tools etc).

Comment: I've checked the folders are as in GitHub.  However, the CSS for the styling is from the template I'm using.  Even when switch to a basic template, none of the Geshi style come through. Any way to tell if Geshi is actually working (it is enabled)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Geshi plugin has been removed from Joomla which is why it won't be working. You can see the pull request for it here:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/746

To highlight your code from now on, you will need to use a 3rd party extensions from the [Coding & Scripts Integration](http://extensions.joomla.org/category/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration)  category.

Comment: I can still see the Geshi plugin folder in my install, but clearly they are not in play.

Comment: Actually this isn't true. The Geshi plugin has been removed from core however it will continue to work on existing installations

Comment: @GeorgeWilson - How does it continue to work if it has been removed from core?

Comment: Because the plugin was never uninstalled. It was just no longer shipped with new installations - so it just should work like any other plugin

Comment: Fair enough. Clearly something hasn't been done correctly when removing it else it would work for the OP

Comment: Nope. Because it was removed in Joomla 3.1. If it worked through out 3.2 then there was nothing done wrong when removing it

Comment: Especially if the code tags are still being modified by the plugin :)

Comment: Then I might be wrong about Geshi modifying the <pre> tag. When I look at the style that is applied to the code, the CSS is from the template I'm using for the site.  I must have done something to disable Geshi and can't get it working again.

Comment: Use the new URL with the word search "syntax".  Gives you a better result.