# Displaying Syntax highlighting and indentions. Specifically for Java, C#?

Tags: joomla-3.6

I've seen other options for some languages, like PHP, HTML and CSS, but nothing for Java and C#.  Also it needs to be current, for Joomla 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

[CedHighlightjs](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/cedhighlightjs/) (free) and [JExtBOX Code Display](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/jextbox-code-display) (paid) seem to support highlighting of Java and C.

There may be others.

See the answer at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18817/120 for some other possible options.