Show code viewer in my article
I'm a programmer. I want to show my codes and scripts inside a joomla (4) article, something like below:

This image has taken from this site. As it can be seen, line numbers are supported which is important for me. Furthermore, codes are color formatted which is not necessary. Is there any extension or plugin for what I mentioned?
I should notice that my purpose is not see php codes of joomla. I want to put a c++ code for instance and describe it for c++ programmers.

This has been answered at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18817/120

Searching on "syntax highlighting" may help you find what you are looking for.
